# Cannot assign JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am using following code to take a json list from my url:

```
  List<Item> songList = new List<Item>();

  var w = new SharpGIS.GZipWebClient();

  Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
    .Subscribe(r =>
    {
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Phone>(r.EventArgs.Result);
                  songList = deserialized.songs.items;

     });
  w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myURL.com/"));

  List<ExtendedItem> extendedItemList = organizeBundleAndUri(songList);
```

Here when debugging I can see that deserialized.songs.items list has 11 elements.

But when it comes to last line songList has 0 element. Why can I not asign "deserialized.songs.items" object
 value to songList?

If I use it as below:

```
  SongList.ItemsSource = deserialized.songs.items;
```

I can see the data list on my main page.

Btw it is my first time coding C#, I am a Java developer. So if it is a lame question, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to use WebClient or HttpClient? They have *awaitable* methods like `GetStringAsync` or `DownloadStringTaskAsync`

Comment: I tried HttpClient, but couldn't manage to work properly. So I carried the entire code to main page cs and now do all the logic in call back as Dan mentioned in the answer. Tha is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `DownloadStringAsync` is asynchronous, and therefore returns immediately before `songList` will have been assigned.  You need to do everything you want to do after you download the song list in the call-back (the code in the block after `r =>`).  If this means you call a method, that works, too:

```
 List<Item> songList = new List<Item>();

 var w = new SharpGIS.GZipWebClient();

 Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
    .Subscribe(r =>
    {
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Phone>(r.EventArgs.Result);
                  songList = deserialized.songs.items;

        List<ExtendedItem> extendedItemList = organizeBundleAndUri(songList);
        // DoSomethingElse(extendedItemList);
    });
 w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myURL.com/"));
```

Comment: This code block is in a fuction which I need to return extendedItemList. Is there way I can return the value?

Comment: If the `GZipWebClient` has a `DownloadString` method to match its asynchronous counterpart, you could use that, and force this method to be synchronous.  It wouldn't return until after the call was done.  Not being familiar with the library, that is only a guess though.

Comment: I carried the entire code to main page xmal cs and now do all the logic in call back as you mentioned in the answer. That is working fine now, since I can set the final result to my dataContext. Thanks.